# How to find a div element in DOM code with selenium webdriver and python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to detect non mobile friendly websites by getting their document width using selenium webdriver  and python 2.7.

How I plan to get this work with selenium webdriver and python:

1. open Chrome webdriver in a small sized window silimar to mobile phones device width
2. open the URL and read its **DOM html page code**
3. Look for `<div id="Wrapper"` (or similar) in the body of the DOM code of the website.
4. If `<div id="Wrapper"` is larger than 430px (the max width of most mobile phones), print the URL and `'website not reponsive'` message

So two questions:

1. is this a **reliable** way tot detect non mobile websites?
2. how do I look for the element which determines the width of a website's content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can do:

```
driver.execute_script("return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);")
```

Will return a boolean if it's a mobile device based on user agent.

To get the width you can do:

```
driver.execute_script("return document.body.offsetWidth;")
```

This will return an integer for the current width, in pixels, of the document body.

Then there's also one built into selenium, which will give you the browser size. Keep in mind if you're using Chrome's mobile emulation this will give you a false value.

```
driver.get_window_size()
```

This will return a dictionary with keys `height` and `width`.

Comment: very helpful, thanks!